# How to Stop Toast.makeText When close dialog or exit app

Tags: android, toast, seekbar, android-alertdialog

Again. I create app to change TextSize by use SeekBar in `Dialog Alert`. When i use `seekBar` `TextSize` will change and show font number by `Toast.makeText`. However `Toast.makeTake` don't stop an increase number,show message. it's not stop when dialog close and exit app. I must force close app in Setting or Uninstall app. It' will be stop. How can i fix this.
Thank again.

```
  public void ShowDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(this);

    seek.setMax(100);

    popDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.conp);
    popDialog.setTitle(R.string.menu_settings);
    popDialog.setView(seek);

    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {

            subtitles.setTextSize(progress);

            Toast.makeText(ShowMan.this, "your textsize :" + String.valueOf(progress), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    // Button
    popDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    popDialog.create();
    popDialog.show();
}
```

& My teacher say "Don't use Dialog Theme.

Comment: I just want to close Toast.makeTake when dialog dismiss and stop increasing number. How can I fix this ?

Comment: & this 2.                                                                 Toast.makeText(ShowMan.this, "your textsize :" + String.valueOf(progress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Toast.makeText(ShowMan.this, "your textsize :" + String.valueOf(progress), 2000).show();                                     not work.

Answer (score 0):

Write that Toast under onStopTrackingTouch()

```
public void ShowDialog() {
final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(this);
int pgSeekbar;

seek.setMax(100);

popDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.conp);
popDialog.setTitle(R.string.menu_settings);
popDialog.setView(seek);

seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {

        subtitles.setTextSize(progress);

        pgSeekbar = progress;
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        Toast.makeText(ShowMan.this, "your textsize :" + pgSeekbar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});

// Button
popDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

popDialog.create();
popDialog.show();
```

Comment: I will try this. wait a second

Comment: I edited the code. Now try that.
Changed the toast duration to Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

Comment: Yeah I' trying. My emulator slow. wait second.